# Text Translation in C# (Windows and Linux)

Tags: c#, php, mono, translation

I am looking into making a c# application that should run on Windows and Linux (Mono) and am looking into making an automated translations tool. I'm looking for a free translation service to achieve this either using a c# api (as long as it is mono compatible) or a php api. I've looked at google but their service is no longer free and bing looks as if it isn't free either anymore, or at least won't be in August of 2012 as AppID are being deprecated and is done via Windows Azure Market place.

Are there any other free translation tools available that could do what I want to achieve.

Thanks for any help you can you provide.

Comment: Accurate, convenient, free: pick one.

Answer (score 1):

The only free alternative I can think of is the Translation Engine of [WebServiceX.NET](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wsdetails.aspx?wsid=63)

Comment: Any idea how to use it?